# Ubuntu 18.04. Gracefull Shutdown

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I am having this issue with Ubuntu 18.04. where it does not shutdown gracefully and then boots into Grub recovery mode when I start it back up. This typically happens if I don't close each and every program properly before shutdown. I am aware this is caused by the faulty shutdown behavior of certain programs. However, this does not make it any better as there are many programs which don't close themselves properly on shutdown and I have no influence on this. This is not very convenient. Is there maybe a way to avoid this?

What should happen (how it works on Windows for example):

- When I power off a screen should appear showing me a list of programs which are still open and asking me if I want to aboard the power off to save my progress or if I want to proceed with the shutdown.
- In case I proceed with the shutdown Ubuntu closes the programs properly and then powers off.

Intermediate fix: 
You can disable Grub recovery from showing by putting this line into /etc/default/grub :
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="0"
This is not a proper solution though as Ubuntu still fails to shutdown gracefully. Grub recovery mode is merely hidden (not recommended).

Where would I report this issue if I wanted to bring it to Ubuntu developers attention for a possible fix?

Comment: This will very likely be related to your hardware, so you probably should post system specs.

Comment: "This typically happens if I don't close each and every program properly before shutdown." - I have already figured out that this is related to certain programs/ software. The problem only occurs if I don't manually shutdown those programs before powering the system off. One classic example of this is Google Chrome but there are many other programs which don't shutdown gracefully with the system unless they are closed manually.

Comment: I have moved this over to Launchpad as I see it as more of a bug/ wishlist item than a question: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partman-auto/+bug/1856584